# How can I find the caller name with Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I want to get the caller name on either request url or status callback url. I am using C# code for purchasing the numbers.

option parameter is as below:-

```
options.VoiceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUrl"] + "/Home/RaiseCallEvent";
options.StatusCallback = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUrl"] + "/Home/EndCallEvent";
options.PhoneNumber = Number.PhoneNumber;
options.VoiceMethod = "GET";
options.VoiceCallerIdLookup = true; //for getting the caller name
options.StatusCallbackMethod = "GET";
IncomingPhoneNumber = TwilioClient.AddIncomingPhoneNumber(options);
```

I have done the VoiceCallerIdLookup as true now when twilio hits my voice url RaiseCallEvent or status call back url EndCallEvent then in which parameter I can get the caller name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you've enabled `VoiceCallerIdLookup` on your `IncomingPhoneNumber`, then when Twilio makes its HTTP request to your Voice Request URL, it will include a parameter called `CallerName`.  A complete list of all the parameters we send as part of the Voice Request is here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request

Hope that helps.